# Create a custom type to exclude a keyof parameter

Tags: typescript, types

I want to create a custom type in the typescript to be removed when I create an array of interface parameters.

```js
type Private<T> = T

interface Test {
  param1: boolean,
  param2: number,
  param3: string,
  param4: Private<boolean>
}

type NotType<B, C> = Pick<B, {
  [K in keyof B]: B[K] extends C ? never : K
}[keyof B]>

const a: (keyof NotType<Test, Private<any>>)[] = ['param1']
```

But the type I created causes any value I pass to be excluded and not the ones I declared as Private, is there any way to indicate a field to be excluded without the need to declare all parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary problem with that is that TypeScript's type system is *structural*, not *nominal*. (This is unlike the type systems in some other languages, such as Java.) That means type compatibility is determined by the *shape* of the type (what kinds of properties it has), not the *name* of the type. Your `Private<T>` type doesn't do anything, the result of `Private<AnyTypeHere>` is `AnyTypeHere`. ([Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwG4ENgQDwBUB8UC8UWA3AFCmiRQCCBUA3hAB4oC2YANhAFxQDOwRADsA5sQC+ZCuGjV4CVtELzU6DNRxkA9Fqh6AegH5SQA).)

You could use the `Exclude` utility type and a literal property name:

```typescript
interface Test {
    param1: boolean,
    param2: number,
    param3: string,
    param4: boolean,
}

const a: (Exclude<keyof Test, "param4">)[] = ['param1']; // works
const b: (Exclude<keyof Test, "param4">)[] = ['param4']; // fails as desired
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDKHIAOcUcAtgIwBcyARgPaMA2EcIANAUaeRQCY6IAK4V60bkRJlKAZjpYooAOZTesigBY6TVuy54AvnjwJGILMjh0AFAFEAHghYiAJhAA8AawgBPRhg0TDBOZAAiPkotcIA+AEoAbQBdZABeZESAcijqLOSAbmQAemLkAHdGKG8MMwsrejsnF3cvXwCg9CwwyM0YhJT0zJy+-KLS5HhgFgxrWY8MYCgINzwgA)

Or if you have several you want "private", you can create a union of them:

```typescript
interface Test {
    param1: boolean,
    param2: number,
    param3: string,
    param4: boolean,
}
type TestPrivate = "param3" | "param4";

const a: (Exclude<keyof Test, TestPrivate>)[] = ['param1']; // works
const b: (Exclude<keyof Test, TestPrivate>)[] = ['param4']; // fails as desired
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDKHIAOcUcAtgIwBcyARgPaMA2EcIANAUaeRQCY6IAK4V60bkRJlKAZjpYooAOZTesigBY6TVuy54AvnjABPYinRYACsoBucSMgC8yAER9575AB8PXtruANx4eAiMIFjIcHQAFACiAB4ILCIAJhAAPADWEGaMMGiYYJzFtg5OEAB8AJQA2gC6rsj1AOSBVG2NwcgA9H3IAO6MUDkY4ZHR9PHJqRnZeQVF1qXlYHbAjpB1TS3tgVrdvQPI8MAsGDFXmRjAUBDpeEA)

I don't think there's any way you can annotate a `boolean` property inline with the type definition that would allow you to exclude it later except by name or type (and I don't think you want to use type for this, from the question).